# Android studio multiple drawable folder rename

Tags: android, android-studio, xml-drawable

When I created the Android project I am currently working on, there were no folders for drawable-mdpi, drawable-hdpi, drawable-xhdpi, drawable-xxhdpi, drawable-xxxhdpi. I've added these manually.

I've added in the different sized images across each folder and when I rename them, it gives me the option to rename all versions of that image.

I've noticed that versions in the xxxhdpi folder isn't renaming and seems to be being excluded from association with the other versions.

Is there an option in Android Studio to 'include' the drawable folders that I want associated with one another?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tested this in Android Studio 2.0 Beta 5 and it seems to work fine.

I would suggest either updating Android Studio or providing finer reproduction steps or even a quick screen capture to show exactly where in Android Studio you are performing the action from (ie. from the top menu's, project window).

You can also check that Android Studio is recognising your self made folders by choosing the "Android" view in the Explorer window, see attachment:

[image]

Comment: I was using the beta version of Android Studio but ended up rolling back to 1.5 stable. Following your instructions, I can see Android Studio isn't recognising the xxxhdpi. It must not be recognised on the version of AS that I am using. Thanks for your feedback, it's given me an answer so I'll mark it as the correct one.

Comment: You're welcome, yeah it's always a gamble working in the canary channel... but you get to use the cool things first. Even if they don't work so well all the time...